# Resolution when booting with usb on a screenless windows 10 (No monitor connected)

Tags: windows-10, boot, display, resolution

I have been facing a problem with Win 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC  Build 1809, to reset some parameters in the pc an application was developed to run from a bootable USB, that was running for years without a problem, nevertheless i started facing problems when the pc does not have a screen (monitor) connected, if it is screenless the resolution is automatically set to 640 X 480, as the software (WinForms) is developed in 800 X 600 resolution it does not fit anymore in the screen. That makes the application useless, i have tried to run the solution used in this post [Low resolution boot screen on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1723882/low-resolution-boot-screen-on-windows) but it did not worked.

Specific question:

is there a way to force the resolution of the screen in boot mode when no monitor is connected ?

Any advice would be very appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i added  the specific question thank you

Comment: Do you have the option of connecting a display in order to verify the problem isn’t a display adapter driver problem? This application I assume is NOT a Windows application since it’s designed to be ran from a bootable environment, off a USB, which sort of eliminates Windows as being an option.

Comment: I have tested with a display and works properly, as soon as is booted without an screen connected than it is shown with the above mentioned resolution

Comment: Have you seen https://www.tenforums.com/graphic-cards/10681-tutorial-how-change-windows-10-default-resolution.html on setting the default resolution? Not sure if it will work without monitor.