# Windows boot screen resolution is weird

Tags: windows-10, display, screenresolution

During boot, the Windows logo and loading circle got stretched by 3:4 image ratio on 16:9 screen. When it going to login screen, the resolution goes back to 1600x900

I have a PC with specs:

- Asus H61M-K mainboard,
- Intel Core i3-2120 CPU,
- 8 gigs of DDR3 RAM,
- NVIDIA GT 730 (Plugged in VGA Port + iGPU off),
- With Dell E2016HV,
- And OS is Windows 10 22H2 (latest update).

Even after applying answer on [Low resolution boot screen on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1723882/low-resolution-boot-screen-on-windows), everything is more weird.

After using `bcdedit /set {globalsettings} highestmode on`, the screen is stretched like before but in higher resolution *(something like 1600x1200)*. And I can't using `bcdedit /set {globalsettings} graphicsresolution 1600x900` due to error "**The integer value is not valid at specified**". Maybe "`1600x900`" on my command isn't correct. So can anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Is the motherboard UEFI, and if so, is CSM Mode enabled?